# Excel Parameter from Drop down

Tags: excel-2007

I have a datasource that poplulates my sheet from sql server.  There is a parameter to refresh the data.  Can I have the choices come from a drop down menu on another sheet?  I know no VBA BTW.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old but the answer is No.

To add dynmic parameters, you need to use VBA.

Its not hard. Since this queistion is 4 months old you have probably already figured that out.